# AWS IoTDataManager Not Found In Scope

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, aws-sdk

There seems to be a conflict with using Amplify and aws-sdk-ios-spm with SPM so Amplify package was added with SPM and aws sdk added with CocoaPods.

My Podfile is defined as such:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

PLATFORM = '14.0'
platform :ios, PLATFORM
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

def common_pods
  
  # AWS
  
  pod 'AWSCore'
  pod 'AWSIoT'
  pod 'AWSMobileClient'

end

target 'App' do
    common_pods
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings["IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"] = PLATFORM
        end
    end

    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
end
```

I ran `pod install` and `pod update` and everything seems to have installed correctly however when I then try and use it:

```
import AWSCore
import AWSIoT

class ExampleClass {

    private var iotDataManager: AWSIoTDataManager?

    init() {
        self.iotDataManager = AWSIoTDataManager(forKey: "iotKey")
    }

}
```

I just receive the error `Cannot find type 'AWSIoTDataManager' in scope` when declaring `private var iotDataManager` but XCode finds it fine when I `Jump to Definition`.

Any reason why this maybe the case?

Thaks